# Excel formula that deciphers text and outputs properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to have excel read text and decipher whether it does or doesn’t have certain character/letters?

Here is my example sheet

[image: Sheet 1]

I am looking for something that deciphers using
these guidelines. 1. If entry has a / then output
URL. 2. If entry is not a URL and has only numbers
and special characters then output IP. 3. If entry is
not a URL or IP and has more than 1
dots/periods/decimals then output HOST. If entry
is not a URL, IP, or HOST (or only has 1
dot/period/decimal) then output FQDN.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for

[image: output]

I have tried using these below:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/“,””))=1,"URL",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,”.”,""))=1,"FQDN"‚IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",”"))>1,"HOST")))
```

That works for reading URL, HOST, and FQDN;
however, it reads IP's as HOST's.

I have also used

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"A","B","C",”D","E","F”,"G","H","I","J","K",”L”,"M",”N","O","P","Q”,"R","S","T","U","V","W",”X","Y","Z"},A1))),””,"IP")
```

That works for reading if an entry contains letters and if not it outputs IP.

Is there a way to combine these or simplify what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the desired output for your sample (at least)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*/*"),"URL",IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))),"IP",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))>1,"HOST","FQDN")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does work for the sample when the formula is only placed in B1-5. But, say I wanted to have it in B1-10 just in case there was 10 entries and then I only have 5. B6-10 would show “FQDN” even though there is no entry in A6-10.

Comment: Then you could edit it to be `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*/*"),"URL",IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))),"IP",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))>1,"HOST",IF(A1="","","FQDN"))))`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! I really appreciate the help. I tried playing around with it first to see if I could figure it out myself but I’m still learning! Lol Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (tested with O365) :

```
=IFS(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A5)))=TRUE,"IP",LEN(A1:A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,".",""))>1,"HOST",LEN(A1:A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,"/",""))=1,"URL",LEN(A1:A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,".",""))=1,"FQDN")
```

Classical way (in B1) :

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("/",A1))=FALSE,"URL",IF(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A1)))=FALSE,"IP",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))>1,"HOST",IF(ISBLANK(A1)=TRUE,"","FQDN"))))
```

Output :

[image: IP]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I get a #NAME? error. I think it’s because I don’t think I have the =IFS Formula.

Comment: Yes. IFS formula comes along with Excel 365, 2019 & 2021. I've added a workaround.